# Any way to log/monitor unixODBC activity

Tags: sql, unixodbc

Is there anyway, but quite simple way, to monitor or log or see all the queries that are send by our application (running on Linux) to our Oracle Database ?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.easysoft.com/support/kb/kb00945.html

Comment: Waouuu, thank you for your answer... quick and accurate. Best regards